# Zero transformation and inner product

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, inner-products

**Theorem**. *A linear operator $T$ on an inner product space is $0$ if and
only if $\langle a,T(a)\rangle =0$ for all $a$*.

(**Ref**: Hassani, Sadri. Mathematical physics: a modern introduction to its foundations. Springer Science & Business Media, 2013.)

Ok, let's take $\mathbb{R}^2$ with its usual inner product;
$$\langle x,y \rangle :=x^\top y,\ \forall x,y\in \mathbb{R}^2.$$

Now, consider the linear transformation
$$T(x):=[x_2,-x_1]^\top,$$
which satisfies
$$ \langle x,T(x) \rangle=x_1x_2-x_2x_1=0,\ \forall x\in \mathbb{R}^2. $$
But, $T$ is not a zero transformation since, it does not map every vector $x$ to $0$. Where is my mistake?

Comment: Whether the underlying field is real or complex is important here.

Comment: This theorem is false in real numbers, and yours is a valid counterexample.

Comment: Thanks @T.Bongers and @Crostul! now I take the point. It is important to specify whether the vector space is complex or real.